# Why use TimeSpan.CompareTo() rather than < > or =

Tags: c#, .net, timespan, compareto

I've been going over some Microsoft samples of code for the Kinect sensor and have stumbled across the following line.

```
TimeSpan zeroDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0);
TimeSpan timeRemaining = ...;

if (timeRemaining.CompareTo(this.zeroDuration) > 0)
{
}
```

I understand how `CompareTo()` is useful in scenarios such as sorting but why would it be used in a conditional `if()` instead of the more direct approach?

```
if (timeRemaining > this.zeroDuration)
{
}
```

PS: I would take it with a grain of salt if it was from any other source but given the general quality of the code assume there is a reason

Comment: I'd assume it's just a stylistic difference, but I could be wrong. @Amicable that's mainly about different equality comparisons, not `>` vs `CompareTo`.

Comment: For TimeSpans, there is no difference. My guess is that the sample dev wasn't aware that overloaded operators existed.

Comment: @Amicable null comes before a string and it uses CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare, which means it will use a culture-dependant comparison. This might mean that ß will compare equal to SS in Germany, or similar - is not applicable to TimeSpan

Comment: They probably did not know that TimeSpan overloads these operators. Or they have a Java background.

Comment: Comparing structure types is iffy, you'd have to know the implementation.  TimeSpan implements IComparable.  Interfaces exist to encourage a programmer to code against the contract.  So using IComparable.CompareTo() follows the practice.  You are entirely free to ignore it of course, nobody is going to frown on it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both internally does the same thing. Compare `Ticks` and return result.

```
public int CompareTo(TimeSpan value) {
    long t = value._ticks;
    if (_ticks > t) return 1;
    if (_ticks < t) return -1;
    return 0;
}

 public static bool operator <(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2) {
            return t1._ticks < t2._ticks;
}
```

The only reason could be the other overload for [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3she1h3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which receives an `object` type parameter checks for `null` and then compare. Implemented like:

```
public int CompareTo(Object value) {
            if (value == null) return 1;
            if (!(value is TimeSpan))
                throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeTimeSpan"));
            long t = ((TimeSpan)value)._ticks;
            if (_ticks > t) return 1;
            if (_ticks < t) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
```

Source code from: [Reference Source .NET Framework 4.5.1 - Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs#865ef7b89f41b632)

Comment: That is the link I was looking for for my own answer! +1